# Is it possible to retain senders IP information on backend server when using iptables as reverse proxy?

Tags: iptables, reverse-proxy

Lets say I have 2 servers: 1.1.1.1 and 2.2.2.2

I have forwarded all traffic to all ports on 1.1.1.1 to 2.2.2.2 using iptables

```
iptables -A FORWARD -d 2.2.2.2 -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1:65500 -j ACCEPT #forward tcp port range
iptables -A FORWARD -d 2.2.2.2 -i eth0 -p udp -m udp --dport 1:65500 -j ACCEPT #forward udp port range
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 1.1.1.1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1:65500 -j DNAT --to-destination 2.2.2.2  #tcp port range
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 1.1.1.1 -p udp -m udp --dport 1:65500 -j DNAT --to-destination 2.2.2.2  #udp port range
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

I can now access everything that is hosted at 2.2.2.2 masked behind 1.1.1.1.

My issue now is box 2.2.2.2 IP logs shows all incoming traffic as coming from 1.1.1.1.

Is there any way to retain this setup while telling box 2.2.2.2 what the original IP address is?

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve? Why did you choose IPTables DNAT as your tool?

Comment: I am trying to utilize a ddos protected VPS located in Europe (1.1.1.1) as a "complete" reverse proxy for a VPS located in America (2.2.2.2). The American VPS has DirectAdmin installed and hosts many websites and clients. The goal is for all ports and services that would normally be available on the American VPS to be available via the European VPS. The above iptable settings work exactly how I wanted, except for the fact that all traffic/mail/IP logs only show the European IP (1.1.1.1). For example every user on a forum now has the same IP address of the European IP, which isn't what I wanted

Answer (score 0):

You are masquerading the source IP with the one from eth0, that is why the destination machine is seeing just the 1.1.1.1 IP. You should not use masquerade but route traffic from the 2.2.2.2 box to the router.

Comment: Do I simply negate the last line of my iptables rules, or how do I do that.

Answer (score 0):

The challenge here is to get proper forwarding of traffic from/to the American VPS server.

The `-j MASQUERADE` rule is required so that return packets from American VPS are routed properly back via European VPS. However, that requires changing the IP address in the packet.

An alternative approach without `MASQUERADE` rule requires setting up custom routing tables at American VPS server. With this approach, one cannot connect to American server IP address from the Internet at all.

All these operations should be done on the American VPS console, not via SSH.

1: Find out the default router for American VPS:

```
ip route | grep default
```

2: Add custom route to European VPS server. `<IP>` is the IP address from step 1.

```
ip route add 1.1.1.1 via <IP>
```

3: Add default route via European VPS:

```
ip route add default via 1.1.1.1
```

4: Delete previous default route:

```
ip route del default via <IP>
```

Next step is to remove the `MASQUERADE` rule on European VPS:

```
iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

To enable outbound traffic from the US VPS, you need to add a different MASQUERADE rule on the same EU VPS server:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -i tun0 -j MASQUERADE
```

This rule enables outbound communication from the US VPS to general internet. `tun0` is the interface name of your VPN tunnel.

After this setup, the American VPS IP address cannot be reached from the Internet, all traffic is routed via the European VPS.

Before deploying this setup to production use, you should understand all the principles involved in the setup to ensure you can maintain the setup properly.

Comment: I haven't tried this yet, as my question now revolves around the DirectAdmin on the American VPS. You said your solution would prevent the American IP from being reachable over the internet, but would this prevent DirectAdmin from communicating with their licensing servers? Should I change my licensed IP address for DirectAdmin from the American IP to the European IP, or would DirectAdmin still correctly know its installed on the American IP?

Comment: I actually forgot one part in my answer regarding outbound traffic from the server. I also updated the answer. However, all traffic originating from the US server will go to European VPS server, and have European server's address as source IP.

Comment: The last MASQUERADE rule is run from the American VPS after removing the previous MASQUERADE rule from the European VPS? I'm assuming I also have to install VPN on the European VPS and configure it on the American VPS since it references tun0? Otherwise I'm confused by the tun0 part of the new MASQUERADE rule. I suppose thats what you meant by "Before deploying this setup to production use, you should understand all the principles involved in the setup to ensure you can maintain the setup properly."

Comment: The MASQUERADE rule is added to the EU server. And yes, you need a VPN tunnel between the two servers.